# MySQL STR_TO_DATE ends as a "0" (zero)

Tags: mysql, zero, str-to-date

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1.1.2000 0:00:00','%e.%c.%Y')` will end up like `2000-01-01`

but when I'm trying to do the same on column with values `1.1.2000 0:00:00` by running

```
SELECT 
FirstDisplayedDate,
FirstDisplayedDate = STR_TO_DATE(FirstDisplayedDate,'%e.%c.%Y')
FROM product
```

I will get zero (NOT NULL!) in every row.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function is the **inverse** of the `DATE_FORMAT()` function. It takes a string `str` and a format string format.

`STR_TO_DATE()` returns a `DATETIME` value if the format string contains **both** date and time parts, or a `DATE` or `TIME` value if the string contains **only** date or time parts.

If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from `str` **is illegal**, `STR_TO_DATE()` returns `NULL` and produces a warning.

The server scans `str` **attempting** to match format to it. The format string **can contain** literal characters and format specifiers beginning with `%`. Literal characters in format **must** match literally in `str`. Format specifiers in format **must** match a date or time part in `str`.

And, the reason to get zero is that **unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0**, so incompletely specified values in `str` **produce a result with some or all parts set to 0**, for example:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('abc','abc');
            -> '0000-00-00'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
        -> '0000-09-00'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%s');
        -> '00:00:09'
```

Check in your query which format to use for date/time matching and make sure your database rows contains *strings*, which can be converted as dates and do not assign output values from the function to the same database field:

```
SELECT 
  FirstDisplayedDate,
  STR_TO_DATE(FirstDisplayedDate,'%e.%c.%Y') AS Converted
FROM product
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is more information how to use the function properly.

Answer (score 0):

You get what you write: `FirstDisplayedDate = STR_TO_DATE(FirstDisplayedDate,'%e.%c.%Y')` compares `FirstDisplayedDate` with `STR_TO_DATE(FirstDisplayedDate,'%e.%c.%Y')` and if they are not equal returns zero. I think you want to use alias here so:

```
SELECT 
  FirstDisplayedDate,
  STR_TO_DATE(FirstDisplayedDate,'%e.%c.%Y') AS FirstDisplayedDate2
FROM product
```